# void WndProc Messages

Tags: windows, events

Im trying to find a **list/article** of messages that can be passed in the following override.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {}
```

I have found this [link on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) but im looking for a full list of available messages in order to take full advantage of them in my apps.

Is there any such public **KB article** that list them ?

Comment: There are an infinite number of possible messages. The basic messages are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632586(v=vs.85).aspx) but there are plenty of control-specific messages, as well as registered messages.